# how to fix the error: ‘::max_align_t’?

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-15.04

I get the error

> "/usr/include/c++/5/cstddef:51:11: error: ‘::max_align_t’ has not been declared
>      using ::max_align_t;
>              ^"

So I should update the libraries because I find this solution:

**"A workaround until libraries get updated is to include `<cstddef>` or `<stddef.h>` before any headers from that library."**

I wrote some command on the Ubuntu terminal such as:

```
bash $ sudo apt-get install apt-file
bash $ sudo apt-file update
bash $ apt-file search stddef.h
```

Then still the error exist.
Thank you

Comment: What were you trying to compile?

Comment: @Azadeh, you need to give us more information. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to run a program that gives you this error? Or are you getting this error while you try to compile some file of you?

Comment: Text must come from https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/porting_to.html . Those ubuntu commands are rather useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `.cpp` file where this compile error occurs you need to add

```
#include <cstddef>
```

before any of the other headers, e.g.

**main.cpp (broken)**

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    using ::max_align_t;
    puts("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Try to compile that:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o test main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:10: error: ‘::max_align_t’ has not been declared
  using ::max_align_t;
      ^
```

Then fix it:

**main.cpp (fixed)**

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    using ::max_align_t;
    puts("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o test main.cpp
$ ./test
Hello World
```

Comment: While `max_align_t` might be in the global namespace on that implementation, it's not guaranteed. Consider correcting your post.

Comment: @Deduplicator True, but the OP's error is exactly as illustrated and the OP seems to be a) very green, b) not a fluent English
speaker. Perhaps best to keep it simple, but feel free to add a refining addendum if you wish.

Comment: Thanks so much Mike Kinghan, Now the newer error "narrowing conversion of long long int to long unsigned int inside {} [-Wnarrowing]!

Comment: I think error got from
 [code]
const unsigned long int factorial[17] = {1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600, 6227020800, 87178291200, 1307674368000, 20922789888000};[/code]

Comment: @Azadeh Welcome to Stackoverflow! If my answer solved the problem you posted, see [how to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If you now have a new problem, then post a new question. That's how Stackoverflow works. Before you post your new question, see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so that this time you will not get down-votes.

Comment: accepted it, thank you, I ask the new question on this page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136988/narrowing-conversion-of-long-long-int-to-long-unsigned-int-inside-wnarrowin

Answer (score 0):

I compiled some code with GNU C++ 4.9 on CentOS, and the issue was not solved by ensuring top position #include  (or by the older header name stddef.h).

Weird enough, I searched all header files of the compiler libraries for the global definition of max_aling_t as declared in the offending *using* declaration... and found none! Could it be in some 'internal compiled header?

So I simply commented-out the "using ::max_align_t;" line in the standard header (not proud of doing this indeed) and it solved the problem... and code is running...

if anyone can explain what is the meaning/impact of this max_align_t ?

Answer (score -1):

I also commented-out the `using ::max_align_t;` line in `/usr/include/c++/4.9/cstddef`, while, code is running, but I don't know if there are any consequences by doing this...

Comment: You should never ever patch system headers if you "don't know the consequences". My crystal ball says `std::max_align_t` won't compile after this.